# Coronavirus in NYC: What is happening in the near-term?

Tags: epidemics-modeling

Although I am motivated to have some different questions answered (see below), I would like to build or use a model to predict the number of COVID-19 Cases in NYC in the near term (perhaps through the first week of April). Please regard this post as a reference request for models for this statistic.

I am a mathematician at City College of New York who is alarmed at the coronavirus numbers coming out of the city. I am not an epidemiologist. New York City is the current epicenter of the epidemic in the US, with cases growing substantially faster than elsewhere in the country. This is probably due to the density of the population. I think the people of the city deserve to understand what the city is about to experience, and I couldn't find good predictions (preferably aimed at the NYC experience).

I base my understanding of current numbers of infected on data coming from the [NY Department of Health](https://coronavirus.health.ny.gov/county-county-breakdown-positive-cases). This page only displays the current snapshot, but the data has been compiled in the [covid-19-ny github respository](https://github.com/kgjenkins/covid-19-ny). I have posted a [Jupyter notebook on my website](http://wphooper.com/covid19/) in which I generate the graphs attached to this post.

Up until very recently, the confirmed cases in NYC was doubling every 1.55 days. This is the graph supporting this observation generated in the jupyter file mentioned above. For reasons indicated below, it is not clear if this pattern has broken in recent days or not.

[image: graph supporting this observation]

> **Question:** When will there be a substantial deviation from this exponential growth rate? In particular, will the pattern hold for the next 7 days (until April 2nd)?

Note that the graph decreases in slope in the last 3 or 4 days. The hopeful reason to believe this decrease is the drastic measures enforcing and encouraging social distancing in the city and state. Also of course awareness of the issue has grown in the public.

However, I fear the real reason for the decrease in slope is less pleasant. In the graph below, I show the number of newly confirmed cases each day. We observe that in recent days the number of newly confirmed cases is hovering around 3000. According to [covidtracking.com](https://covidtracking.com/data/state/new-york/#history) the number of tests performed on Wednesday, March 25th in New York State was 12,209. Presumably about half of those tests were conducted in New York City, and the rate of positive tests statewide was about 42%.

[image: another graph]

The positive test rate is probably slightly higher in the city. This means that you can't expect the number of confirmed cases to go up much more than 50% of 6000, which is more or less in line with the number of newly confirmed cases in recent days. Thus, I would expect that the number of newly confirmed cases in the city to begin growing linearly (with slope ~3000) unless testing capacity increases dramatically, despite the fact that we would continue to see exponential growth at some rate if there was ample testing.

This belief is inline with recent news articles [suggesting that hospitals are being recommended to only test patients who show symptoms of the virus if they require hospitalization](https://www.buzzfeednews.com/article/laurenwolfe/nyc-tells-doctors-told-not-to-have-a-coronavirus-test). I believe the [original advisories are here](https://www1.nyc.gov/site/doh/covid/covid-19-providers.page). In the absence of the ability to test everyone, I expect criteria for a confirmed case will need to be changed as occurred in China.

Taken together, I believe this suggests that the number of confirmed cases is no longer a meaningful statistic in NYC. I suggest the last day of meaningfulness is around March 23rd. If you believe the growth rate of doubling every 1.55 days persisted beyond that date, then given enough testing, the number of confirmed cases in NYC would be have been 29000 yesterday, March 25th, and would be about 46000 today, March 26th.

In the **massively over-simplistic model** of unabated exponential growth, the number of "confirmed" cases becomes rapidly horrific. By April 2nd, there would be 1 million confirmed cases of COVID-19 in NYC. I am not an epidemiologist, so I do not want to suggest that this behavior will persist to this date or even that it is currently ongoing.

Let me point out some issues.

Certainly continued exponential growth is impossible in a finite population. However NYC has 8.6 million people, so it is also not clear it is an issue in the near term I am discussing.

I don't understand the effect social distancing and the mass school and workplace closings will have. There is a lag between when someone is infected and when they are confirmed. Certainly changes to the trajectories due to societal changes will not manifest in the data for a while after the changes are made.

We don't really understand the number of people who are asymptomatic. (In Iceland it is possibly 50%.) This could cause exponential growth to slow sooner than we might otherwise expect.

I don't know of good comparisons in other places of the world. Are there similar densely populated cities in Italy that have already been through this? Is Wuhan a good model?

**Final remark:** I believe mathematicians are morally obligated to act in the current epidemic, and to attempt to steer policy. NYC is already largely shut down, and I regret not realizing what was going on before recently. In other parts of the world, there may still be an opportunity to have a substantial impact on policy.

Comment: That paper (and subsequent) are worth to consider: Coronavirus: Why You Must Act Now. 
Tomas Pueyo:  https://medium.com/@tomaspueyo/coronavirus-act-today-or-people-will-die-f4d3d9cd99ca

Comment: Washigton Post provided oversimplified but beautiful visualizations what is going on: https://www.washingtonpost.com/graphics/2020/world/corona-simulator/

Comment: State of art analysis provided by Imperial College Group of Neil Ferguson: https://www.imperial.ac.uk/mrc-global-infectious-disease-analysis/news--wuhan-coronavirus/ and previous reports

Comment: I am sympathetic to your concerns. To make this post a better fit to this forum, I recommend adding a brief preface closer to the forum goals.  To me the preface would go something like: "Although I am motivated to have some different questions answered (see below), I would like to build or use a model to predict [[put your main statistic here, e.g. number of actual cases]]. Please regard this post as a reference request for models for this statistic. Other information is also welcome at [[put alternate contact on user page]]." Gerhard "Wants To Make Things Better" Paseman, 2020.03.26.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman even with your changes, I suspect this question would be inappropriate for this site, and more appropriate, for example, at the stats.SE.

Comment: The coronavirus will disappear by June (or not). This is not a math research question.

Comment: The number of "confirmed" cases of infection has no signification, nowhere. It depends of how and how much testing is done, which varies from place to place and from day to day. No one here has any idea of the number of real *cases*. It may be twice, ten times, 100 times, or even 1000 times the number of "confirmed" cases. Can you give a convincing argument that it is impossible that there is now, in the US 80 million people infected, or more? And by the way, this would be very good news.

Comment: As for the **final remark** the only real way mathematicians can help now is by washing their hands regularly.

Comment: @Mark careful, that's how Pontius Pilate got into trouble. Matthew 27:24.